# Помогите понять работу return

Tags: java, методы, return

Хотел бы понять как работает return, в принципе я понимаю как он работает. Но встал вопрос, в примере ниже я запускаю метод с пустым массивом, в методе массив заполняется, и возвращается массив, этот массив занимает место пустого? и получается если запускать метод с параметром, то return вернет значение этому аргументу? А если без аргумента?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ex{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
        int arrSize=0;
        int []ourArray;
        System.out.print("Enter size of array ");
        arrSize=scr.nextInt();
        ourArray=new int[arrSize];
        arrayLength test = new arrayLength();
        test.enterValue(ourArray);


            /*for (int i=0;i<ourArray.length ;i++ ) {
                System.out.print(ourArray[i]+" ");
            }*/

            maxminavr test2=new maxminavr();
            test2.maxNum(ourArray);
            test2.minNum(ourArray);
            test2.avrNum(ourArray);
        }
    }
```

класс с заполнением массива

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class arrayLength{
    Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
    private int [] newArray;
    public int[] enterValue(int []arrEnt){
        newArray=arrEnt;
        for (int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++ ) {
            newArray[i]=scr.nextInt();
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: то есть newArray пустой? и я могу не возвращать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но встал вопрос, в примере ниже я запускаю метод с пустым массивом, в
>   методе массив заполняется и возвращается массив, этот массив занимает
>   место пустого?

Нет, это и есть тот пустой массив.

В `enterValue`:

```
public int[] enterValue(int []arrEnt){
    newArray=arrEnt;
    for (int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++ ) {
        newArray[i]=scr.nextInt();
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

- Вы передаете **ссылку** на `arrEnt`
- В переменную `newArray` записываете **ссылку** на `arrEnt`: `newArray = arrEnt;`. Т.е. выражение `newArray = arrEnt;` не сделает копию массива, а сохранит ссылку на массив в переменную `newArray`
- Заполняете массив **по ссылке**, т.е. `arrEnt`: `newArray[i] = ...`
- Возвращаете **ссылку** на `arrEnt`: `return newArray;`

Таким образом, вы в этом коде заполняете `ourArray` и только его:

```
    ourArray=new int[arrSize];
    arrayLength test = new arrayLength();
    test.enterValue(ourArray);
```

---

> и получается если запускать метод с параметром, то return вернет
>   значение этому аргументу?

Как писал выше из `return` вернется этот же аргумент, а точнее ссылка на тот же массив

> А если без аргумента?

Будет ошибка при компиляции

---

Т.е. смысл вам возвращать массив в текущем виде нет, поэтому можно переписать функцию как:

```
public void enterValue(int []arrEnt){
    newArray=arrEnt;
    for (int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++ ) {
        newArray[i]=scr.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Случай, когда нужно возвращать массив -- это если в аргумент вы передаете массив, внутри функции *создаете новый массив*, что-то с ним делаете на основе массива из аргумента, а после из функции *возвращаете новый массив*.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ

Answer (score 4):

относительно поставленного вопроса gil9red ответил.

Но я бы хотел посоветовать избегать изменения переданных объектов внутри функции(в том числе и массивов)

То есть данный код лучше переписать так:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ex{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
        int arrSize=0;
        System.out.print("Enter size of array ");
        arrSize=scr.nextInt();
         ourArray=new int[arrSize];
        arrayLength test = new arrayLength();
        int[] ourArray = test.enterValue(arrSize);


            /*for (int i=0;i<ourArray.length ;i++ ) {
                System.out.print(ourArray[i]+" ");
            }*/

            maxminavr test2=new maxminavr();
            test2.maxNum(ourArray);
            test2.minNum(ourArray);
            test2.avrNum(ourArray);
        }
    }

import java.util.Scanner; 
class arrayLength{
    Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
    private int[] newArray;
    public int[] enterValue(int size){
        newArray=new int[size];
        for (int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++ ) {
            newArray[i]=scr.nextInt();
        }
        return newArray;
    }}
```

Comment: подскажите почему лучше избегать изменения?

Comment: Сильно усложняет систему, ее дальнейшую поддержку и поиск ошибок. Если данный метод будет написан одним разработчиком, а второй будет его использовать, при этом имя метода никак не говорит о том, что на самом деле переданный объект будет изменен, то использующий данный метод разработчик может не ожидать такого события, и допустить ошибку в своем алгоритме. Подробнее можно узнать в книге "Совершенный код" Стив Макконнелл